# How select rows with multiple conditions and calculate a new column in the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to use the following code:

```
raw_data.loc[(raw_data['PERMNO']==10006)&(raw_data['month']>=50)&(raw_data['month']<=100)]['resi']=raw_data['RET']-raw_data['ewretd']
```

that is based on the conditions to calculate column 'resi'.

But I keep getting warnings like

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
"""Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

How to correct this?

Comment: Did you read the documentation the warning message links you to? It's very thorough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `df.copy`:

```
raw_data = raw_data.copy()
raw_data.loc[(raw_data['PERMNO']==10006)&(raw_data['month']>=50)&(raw_data['month']<=100), 'resi'] = raw_data['RET'] - raw_data['ewretd']
```

Comment: but I need to calculate in the same dataframe

Comment: @Canvas Edited my answer, add this line before your code

Comment: Still the same warning. Actually, there is no column 'resi' in the dataframe, should I insert the column first?